# Direction of current flow in SMPS flyback converter doesn't make sense

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm analyzing this Astrodyne TDI 15W SMPS and I'm confused as to why the dot on the secondary is on top. I calculated the secondary voltage to be 120*(3/70) = 5.1V and this made sense given the schematic but the dot would indicate it's actually -5.1V?

I got the schem from here on page 666: https://archive.org/details/the-art-of-electronics-3rd-ed-2015_202008/page/665/mode/2up?view=theater

You can find this product here: https://store.astrodynetdi.com/15w-ultraminiature-open-frame-switching-power-supplies-ofm-15-ofm15ofm-1501.html
[image]

Comment: With a flyback converter, the primary voltage isn’t what you guess it is - for 240VAC in, the DC rail voltage is around 320V.  The peak primary voltage in flyback is determined by D2.

Answer (score 5):

The flyback "transformer" is actually a coupled inductor and not a conventional transformer.

During the "on" time energy is stored in the magnetic field and current ramps in the primary inductance.  No current flows in the secondary *because* the dot is opposite the primary and the output diode is reverse biased. (D5).

When the switch turns off, the stored magnetic energy forward biases the output diode, and current flows into the output caps.

It's much more like a boost converter than a forward converter for example.

There's some nice discussion in this answer: [Flyback voltage in Flyback Converters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254638/flyback-voltage-in-flyback-converters)

Answer (score 3):

I think you haven't accounted for the rectification diodes here: -

[image]

For a **conventional** AC transformer circuit, when current **enters** the primary terminal marked with a dot, load current **exits** the secondary on the terminal marked with a dot.

For a **flyback** circuit, the situation is different in that current **exiting** the dot on the primary also **exits** the dot on the secondary but at different phases of the switching cycle.